# PHP error at line 15 i would like assistance

Tags: php

I keep getting an error for this code. What is the problem?
The error occurs at line 15 of the code

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
$val=array(1,1,1,1,1);
$count=1;
$average=0;
$total=0;
for ($count=0; $count<5; $count++){
        $val[$count]=rand(0,10);
        echo $val["$count"]."<br />";
} $count=1;

foreach($val as $count) {
$total+=$val[$count];   
}
$average=$total/$count;
echo "the average is  ".$average;

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show us what line 15 is in your case. Also show us the error you are getting, because we can't help you if we don't know what and where it goes wrong.

Comment: And what is the error message you get ?

Comment: $total+=$val[$count];  this is line 15 and the error message is "Notice: Undefined offset: 9 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Deshad files\average2.php on line 15"

Comment: also btw i know i could do it in one loop but i have to do it in two loops

Comment: With `foreach($val as $count)` you get the *values*, not the *keys*. In your earlier `for` loop, you set those to a random value between 0 and 10. The array `$val` only has 5 entries, so if the value is 5 or higher, you will get an undefined index notice. Instead, what I *think* you're trying to accomplish is `$total += $count;`.

Comment: thanks alot rickdenhaan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you should replace

```
$total+=$val[$count];
```

with

```
$total += $count;
```

where $count in foreach  is the random number you set in $val array